# Laplace transform of the improper integral of a function

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

i need to solve this ODE using Laplace transform. $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function. $x$ and $x'$ both have a Laplace Transform.

$$ x'(t) = \sin(2t)\theta(t-\pi)+\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau~~~~, ~~~~~x(0)=0 $$

I'm having trouble with the improper integral.
By definition know that:
$$ \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt $$

So

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau\right\}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau dt $$

Since $e^{-st}$ does not depend of $\tau$

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau\right\}(s)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)d\tau dt $$

And using a Laplace Transform Table the equation would be:

$$sX(s) = e^{-\pi s}\frac{2}{s^2+4} + \int_0^\infty \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)d\tau dt ~~~~,~~~~X(s)=\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}(s)$$

As I said before, I am having a lot of trouble with the improper integral... don't really know what to do so i can find $X(s)$ and then do the inverse transform. Really blocked here.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)d\tau dt = \int_0^\infty \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau) \frac{e^{-\tau t}}{e^{-\tau t}}d\tau dt $$
If I change switch $dt$ and $d \tau$
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\tau t} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-s(t-\tau)}x(t-\tau) e^{-\tau t} dt d\tau ≟ \int_0^\infty e^{-\tau t} \mathcal{L}\{x(t-\tau)\}(s) d\tau $$
Now, how can I take this to an expression with $X(s)$?

EDIT2:
Someone told me I could use the convolution product. This solves my problem but i'd really like to know if I could've done something with what I tried in the first place.
$$\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau = 1 \ast x(t) $$

Comment: The theory of distributions allows to say that $\mathcal{L}\left\{\int_0^{\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau\right\}(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-\tau s} X(s)d\tau$

Comment: @reuns thanks for your answer! I edited the question since I couldn't demonstrate what you told me, but i'm sure what you said is correct !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want to calculate the laplace transform of
$$\int_0^{+\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau$$.

As you have written, this is equal to
$$ \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-st} \int_0^{+\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau dt $$

We can rearrange
$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)dtd\tau $$

The term $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)dt$ is the Laplace transform of $x(t-\tau)$, therefore,

$$ \int_0^{+\infty} \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-st}x(t-\tau)dtd\tau  = \int_0^{+\infty} X(s) e^{-s\tau} d\tau = X(s) \int_0^{+\infty}e^{-s\tau}d\tau$$

And because $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-s\tau}d\tau = \frac{1}{s}$,
the answer is:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}x(t-\tau)d\tau = \frac{1}{s}X(s)$$.

Comment: So $\mathcal{L}\{ x(t-\tau) \}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{ x(t) \}(s) = X(s)$  ?

Comment: No. $\mathcal{L}\{x(t-t_0)\} = X(s)e^{-st_0}$. It is a known property of the laplace transform.

Comment: Oh I see. The table I have says that  the Laplace Transform of $\theta(t-t_0) f(t-t_0)$ is $F e^{-t_0s}$. Your expression seems more useful!